# 3 columns with border (vertical rule)

Tags: html, css, parent-child, multiple-columns

I am trying to make 3 columns (via shortcode) with vertical rules in between the columns. I've added a border-right to each of my columns and added a border-left to my last column and now am trying to wrap the second one third column in a div with a class assigned to isolate the second column right border. I've listed my CSS and html below, but can't figure out what I am doing wrong. You can view the site here: www.bookemcreative.com/testsite

```css
.one_third {
border-right: 1px solid #808080;
height: 120px;
padding-top: 30px;
margin-right: 3.8%;
}

.one_third.last {
border-left: 1px solid #808080;
border-right: none !important; }
}

#wrapper .noborder .one_third {
border-right: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="noborder">[one_third last="no"]
<span style="font-size: 24px; font-style: italic; font-family: texgyrescholaitalic;">Browse our Pocket Cards
</span>
<p style="line-height: 1.4em;"><span style="font-size: 13px; font-family: Antic Slab;">Browse our Unique Line of Pocket Cards
starting at $.75 each.
<a href="http://bookemcreative.com/testsite/pocket-cards-2/">Learn More <i class="icon-play" style="font-size: 10px;"></i></a></span></p>
[/one_third]
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the elements with the pseudo selectors. Try this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="one_third"></div>
<div class="one_third"></div>
<div class="one_third"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.one_third:nth-child(1){ 
   border-right: solid 1px #ccc;
}



.one_third:nth-child(3) {
   border-left: solid 1px #ccc;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5dH7/)**

Note: remove the class .noborder
Note1: There are many ways to do this. this is one of them

Comment: How would I adjust my html to accommodate that then? I am rather new to complex divs

Comment: I have made jsfiddle to represent your html - http://jsfiddle.net/Q5dH7/  . Don´t forget to delete the div .noborder

Comment: Ok, that seems to be working, however, it is pushing the last column to a new row — I believe I have to adjust the margins, but not sure by what percent?

Comment: You must give a equal height to the class .one_third .. i supose is height: 120px, so do this .one_third{height:120px;}.. pay attention with percentages and margins...just follow my demo

Comment: I added that but still appears to be pushing the last column down — do I need to adjust my margins? Thank you. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: sorry didnt see the demo before — I will take a look

Comment: remove the margin-right in .one_half, .one_third, .two_third, .three_fourth, .one_fourth {
    /* margin-right: 4%; */
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative; 
}

Comment: is that being added to the functions.php file? I am using a theme within wordpress so adding custom css to that

Comment: Ok, I did notice one little problem, and it is only on the home page where the columns are, so I think it is something within the html — you will notice on the footer that it is no longer going to the edge of the page - there is a white border there: http://bookemcreative.com/testsite/

Comment: It´s another question... remove the padding in media="all"
#main {
/* padding: 55px 10px 45px; */
background: #fff;
clear: both;
}

Comment: @media all {
   #main {
    padding: 55px 10px 45px;
    background: #fff; 
    clear: both; }
}

Comment: above is what I have tried and doesn't appear to be working yet. Not sure if I added that correctly. I promise i'll leave you alone after this :)

Comment: You forgot to give a right answer in the previous question...about the second question, remove the padding in the #main

Comment: I set the margin to 0% :

Comment: .one_third {
    margin-right: 0% !important;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.two_third {
    margin-right: 0% !important;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.three_fourth {
    margin-right: 0% !important;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.one_fourth {
    margin-right: 0% !important;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
}